# JUnit assertFalse(true) --> successful test case?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, jboss-arquillian

How can this testcase result in a success (i.e. green in my JUnit window):

```
@Test public void caseForXFiles(){
    Assert.assertFalse(true);
}
```

Also, all other sorts of cases succeed although they shouldn't. I assume I don't have to explicitly enable assertions when using this function since I don't use `assert` (even when enabled no difference). Even throwing an unexpected (not even properly compilable) Exception won't color the testcase red. In my second console I get

```
Okt 23, 2014 5:18:43 PM org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.remote.reusable.ReusedSessionPernamentFileStorage readStore
Information: Reused session store is not available at C:\Users\xx\.drone-webdriver-session-store, a new one will be created.
Okt 23, 2014 5:18:54 PM org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXMethodExecutor invoke
Schwerwiegend: Failed: de.xx.MyTest.caseForXFiles
```

What the heck is going on here? I am using JBoss 6.2.4 and Arquillian.

**edit**: After some further investigation I found that this line, as unlikely as it is, causes the problem. My testcase will be shown green in JUnit whilst it is NOT executed (tried with `System.out.print` but didn't show up):

```
@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    rBean.getUserId(); // a simple getter on a String field, no side effects
}
```

It seems that in the `@PostConstruct` of my rBean can't be properly filled. But that this results in the described behavior seems like a bug to me.

**additional info**:
rBean:

```
@Inject @CurrentUser private MyCurrentUser currentUser;
@PostConstruct private void postConstruct() {
    userId = currentUser.getUserId();
}
```

The object currentUser is injected by some company framework to which I don't have access to. Still, I have access to the MyCurrentUser class implementing IUser (no access). Ultimately, I want to run testcases on my Bean methods which have proprietary annotations. I could bypass this by creating test functions that call those annotated functions in which case the annotation won't be looked at.
Problem seems to be that because the currentUser cant `login()`, something at some dark corner goes horribly wrong.

Comment: Assert.assertFalse(true) should definitely fails. Please check org.junit.Assert.class.

Comment: are you not mixing junit 3 and 4 styles? Maybe the @Test is not picked up as Junit 3 is expecting methods that start with testXxxxx

Comment: Please provide more surrounding from your test. Currently the information given is insufficient to diagnose the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, this bug had to do with Arquillian 1.1.4 and was fixed in 1.1.5.

See also [here](http://arquillian.org/blog/2014/06/25/arquillian-core-1-1-5-Final).